# How to extract row with mixed value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have to extract rows from a pandas dataframe with values in 'Date of birth' column which occur in a list with dates.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Name': ['Jack', 'Mary', 'David', 'Bruce', 'Nick', 'Mark', 'Carl', 'Sofie'],
                  'Date of birth': ['1973', '1999', '1995', '1992/1991', '2000', '1969', '1994', '1989/1990']})

dates = ['1973', '1992', '1969', '1989']

new_df = df.loc[df['Date of birth'].isin(dates)]

print(new_df)
```

```
0   Jack          1973
1   Mary          1999
2  David          1995
3  Bruce     1992/1991
4   Nick          2000
5   Mark          1969
6   Carl          1994
7  Sofie     1989/1990
```

Eventually I get the table below. As you can see, Bruce's and Sofie's rows are absent since the value is followed by / and another value. How should I split up these two filter them out?

```
   Name Date of birth
0  Jack          1973
5  Mark          1969
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [str.contains](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html#pandas.Series.str.contains):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Name': ['Jack', 'Mary', 'David', 'Bruce', 'Nick', 'Mark', 'Carl', 'Sofie'],
                   'Date of birth': ['1973', '1999', '1995', '1992/1991', '2000', '1969', '1994', '1989/1990']})

dates = ['1973', '1992', '1969', '1989']

new_df = df.loc[df['Date of birth'].str.contains(rf"\b{'|'.join(dates)}\b")]

print(new_df)
```

**Output**

```
    Name Date of birth
0   Jack          1973
3  Bruce     1992/1991
5   Mark          1969
7  Sofie     1989/1990
```

The string `rf"\b{'|'.join(dates)}\b"` is a regex pattern that will match any of string that contains any of the dates.

Answer (score 2):

I like @DaniMesejo way better but here is a way splitting up the values and stacking:

```
df[df['Date of birth'].str.split('/', expand=True).stack().isin(dates).max(level=0)]
```

Output:

```
    Name Date of birth
0   Jack          1973
3  Bruce     1992/1991
5   Mark          1969
7  Sofie     1989/1990
```

Comment: Thank you for response! I also like @DaniMesejo solution more but yours is fine as well.